# How to save streaming data to Matlab .mat file

Tags: matlab, save, append, streaming, real-time

I am trying to save real-time streaming data obtained from hardware to Matlab workspace, I use the following command: My issue is, it only saved the last set of data, but not all data.

To save all variables from the workspace in binary MAT-file, test.mat, type

```
save test.mat
```

When I tried with this

```
save('test.mat','-append'); ,
```

it makes my program halt, so I would like to know what is the correct way to achieve this?

They have same name and they are constantly overwritten, I did not get error message, I still get the file saved but I noticed that it only showed the latest set of data, what should I do to avoid this? I want it to save every set at each time step

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for appending using save is

```
        save(filename,variables,'-append')
```

This will save append all new variables and overwrite variables already in the filename.mat with the updated values.

Comment: Thank you, but I do not want to overwrite variables, for example, I have five variables in the beginning of my test, I will still have only five variables in the end of my test, but I want to save each value of all five variables from t=1 to t=100 seconds, so I will have 100 sets of five variables (presuming one set data is saved every second)